# How to label x-axis if a sequence is used?

Tags: r, plot

I've this R script:

```
plot(
  seq(2011, 2015),
  main = 'Anzahl vor dem 20 Lebensjahr verstorbener Personen',
  xlab = 'Jahre',
  ylab = 'Tode',
  ylim = c(100, 400)
)

points(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'Jahr'], 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'value'],
  col = 'blue'
)

points(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'Jahr'], 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'value'],
  col = 'red'
)
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: Plot]

My quick question is: How can I achieve, that the x-axis is labeled with the sequence? (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)

#### Tl;dr

My data looks like this:

```
> deaths.data
   Geschlecht Demographisches.Merkmal Jahr value
1        Mann         Unter 20 Jahren 2011   301
2        Frau         Unter 20 Jahren 2011   214
3        Mann         Unter 20 Jahren 2012   285
4        Frau         Unter 20 Jahren 2012   203
5        Mann         Unter 20 Jahren 2013   312
6        Frau         Unter 20 Jahren 2013   212
7        Mann         Unter 20 Jahren 2014   305
8        Frau         Unter 20 Jahren 2014   209
9        Mann         Unter 20 Jahren 2015   323
10       Frau         Unter 20 Jahren 2015   225
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to label the axis with the `axis` function and disable the axis labeling in the `plot` function with the attribute `xaxt="n"`.

Here is the complete result:

```
plot(
  seq(2011, 2015),
  main = 'Anzahl vor dem 20 Lebensjahr verstorbener Personen',
  xlab = 'Jahre',
  ylab = 'Tode',
  ylim = c(100, 400),
  xaxt = 'n'
)

axis(1, at = seq(1, 5), labels = seq(2011, 2015))

points(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'Jahr'], 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'value'],
  col = 'blue'
)

points(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'Jahr'], 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'value'],
  col = 'red'
)
```

This plot is produced:

[image: plot]

Comment: IMO this is the better answer, giving information on how to change specific axis labels in general, rather than fixing your specific problem. (I think this could be the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

`plot(seq(2011, 2015))` does not do what you seem to be expecting it to do. If you feed `plot` a vector, it will plot the values of the vector on the y-axis against their indices on the x-axis.

So this plot would range from 1 to 5 on the x-axis, and would range from 2011-2015 on the y-axis, if you didn't specify `ylim = c(100, 400)`. The points you plot initially, fall outside of this range, so are not shown. You then place the points with your actual data. I suspect that the years in your dataframe also have values of 1 to 5, instead of the actual years. Thats's how these points are plotted on `x=1` tot `x=5`.

To change this, we only have to adjust the value in `deaths.data$years`.

```
plot(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'Jahr'] + 2010, 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Mann', 'value'],
  col = 'blue',
  main = 'Anzahl vor dem 20 Lebensjahr verstorbener Personen',
  xlab = 'Jahre',
  ylab = 'Tode',
  ylim = c(100, 400),
  type = 'p'
)
points(
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'Jahr'] + 2010, 
  deaths.data[deaths.data['Geschlecht'] == 'Frau', 'value'],
  col = 'red'
)
```

In the code above, I added `2010` to the years value. This **should** make the years take `2011-2015` instead of `1-5`. I can't verify, because you didn't show your data in your post.

**After OP edit:**

I tried to reproduce a part of your dataset:

```
deaths.data <- data.frame(Geschlecht = rep("Mann", 5), Jahr = 2011:2015, value = c(301, 285, 312, 305, 323))
```

Using this, my provided code worked (aside from the fact I was missing some commas.

[image]

However, when I changed it to this:

```
deaths.data <- data.frame(Geschlecht = rep("Mann", 5), Jahr = as.character(2011:2015), value = c(301, 285, 312, 305, 323))
```

It provided similar output to what you showed in your question.

[image]

I assume that the years you have in your dataset are stored as characters instead of numerics. **Changing that with `as.numeric` should fix your problem.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work at all:
`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`

Comment: @Robin ouch. In that case, can you show us what exactly `deaths.data` looks like? I can't help much with specific code if I can't try it for myself.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll update my question. Give me a minute.

Comment: sorry I don't get your solution running. It still throws the error from above. see
http://imgur.com/a/nrlN7

Comment: @Robin Your year variable is a factor, that's why it doesn't play nice on a continuous axis. If you change it to numeric values, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally using `ggplot2` :

```
indt<-data.table(
  Geschlecht=
    factor(c("Mann","Frau", "Mann", "Frau", "Mann", 
             "Frau", "Mann", "Frau","Mann", "Frau")),
  Jahr=
    c(2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015),
  value=
    c(301, 214, 285, 203, 312, 212, 305, 209, 323, 225)
)
```

The plot is then created via:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(indt) + geom_point(size=3.5,aes(x=Jahr, y=value, color=Geschlecht))+ggtitle("Anzahl vor dem 20 Lebensjahr verstorbener Personen")+  labs(x="Jahre",y="Tode") +ylim(100,400)
```

[image]